# Trying to make a plane follow a bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying get a plane to follow this form of bezier curve:

[image: curve sample]

Though I'm struggling getting the plane to actually follow the curve. It either does some weird bunching at the spiral or overflows at the other end. The spiral itself is meant to taper till it folds in on itself. Here's what is currently happening. Is it because the bezier is too long compared to the plane? or too short. I know that I'll need to add in more points to the curve itself. Also there is a mesh deformation on the plane to taper it at either end.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You would have much more possibilties to edit the shape if you skip using mesh object and go with curves. E.g you could set straight curve as bevel object to main one and have it as a plane.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that. Do you use the curve and then extrude it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a plane, add [Array](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html) modifier to it for repeating and [Curve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html) modifier - for curvature:

[image]

But why if it's possible to go with curves and avoid any "origin points matching for Curve modifier"? Create 2 curves, 1 - main one (shown above), another one - default curve from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Curve* menu, but just scaled down by one axis (in this case by Y axis) so it's flat.

Then set that curve as bevel object for the main one and in Edit mode scale simple curve to adjust thickness of the main one.

[image]

Adjust curve resolution in the *Shape* rollout, *Preview U* for the simple curve to in-/decrease amount of loopcuts by X axis and *Preview U* for the main curve to in-/decrease amount of loopcuts by Y axis in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

..Not forgetting that you may not need a plane at all... Curves will do this by themselves.. you can always convert to a mesh (Object Mode .. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) when you need to.

[image]

And if you need a taper, you can add a taper curve in the XY plane. (Its X dimension is mapped to the length of the affected curve, Y determines taper amount.)

[image]

Comment: oops.. overlapping answers

Comment: It does include a bit about tapering which is something I needed as well, thanks a lot :)